# How can I detect possible spyware/keyloggers in my computer?

Tags: keyloggers

The reason is because of a recent data leak. I suspected that someone may have inserted keylogger to my computer. (a software, trojan).

Some people think that the only way to really make sure there is no trojan or keyloggers on my computer is to reformat the computer.

Some think that there are other things that's also almost 100%. Things like checking which program to start.

What are those other things? What can I do to detect (and then remove) any keylogers or trojan from my computer?

What I used
1. I used Malwarebytes.
2. I think someone would use other software like hijack this and stuff.

What else can I do to ensure that nobody can keylog my computer?

Some of the answers are here

https://www.wikihow.com/Detect-and-Remove-Keyloggers
https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/how-to-tech/how-to-scan-for-and-remove-spyware1.htm

I could use something more low level. Like scanning any start up programs.

I wonder if there is anything else. Hijackthis? Other scanner I should try?

I may be just paranoid and there could be no keyloggers at all in my computer. However, I handle financial sites and the last databreach cost significant amount of money.

Comment: "However, I notice a vulnerability that only a keylogger can open. I want to get rid of it." What does that mean? What vulnerability did you notice?

Comment: If someone can see everything you type in your computer and your screen then you are in trouble. I want to save my data EVEN if that happens

Comment: You have asked about 3 different things but asked about them as if they are the same: do you want to *detect* a keylogger, or *remove* a keylogger, or *prevent* a keylogger from being installed?

Comment: All 3. Let's start with detecting. That's the most important thing. For preventing I made another question https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/194810/is-it-a-good-idea-to-have-a-new-laptop-just-to-generate-2-fa-keys

Comment: @Anders, I got one of my account hacked. And the info to hack that account is in a text file in my computer.

Comment: Can this be reopened? Anything unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check who is hooking the keyboard API in the system using something like [this](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) or [this](https://www.apimonitor.com/) and work back from there.
However there are many other techniques to achieve this so unless you are experienced with win32 systems and plan to spend a bunch of time I would recommend you to just do a clean install.

p.s
If you want to validate your assumption you could create a new account somewhere and monitor whether someone logs into it, sort of a honeypot account...

Comment: Are you sure those are save? If that program can know what I type, isn't that program a keylogger itself?

Comment: @SharenEayrs please read the details. Those programs are not recording what you type but inspecting what processes hook the keyboard API.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this is the way?